# TensorFlow not showing up in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, conda

I've been trying for a while now to install TensorFlow using Anaconda, but it does not seem to appear.

I am using the Anaconda Navigator, creating multiple environments between python 3.7 to 3.10, and I have also added conda-forge channel to the navigator:
[image: 1]

Whenever I seach for Tensorflow, only tensorflow-related packages like r-tensorflow, tensorboard, keras, etc.:
[image: 2]
I have also tried using the Anaconda Powershell Prompt, but it can also not find TensorFlow

It is worth noting that the powershell prompt does not include conda-forge in its current channels though:
[image: 3]

I am also running this on Windows 10

Comment: Might help to know OS type and version that you are using.  I'm guessing Windows from the Powershell reference, but you should explicitly state that

Comment: I see, I am using Windows 10 Enterprice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channels listed in your powershell output indicate that you are using a 32 bit installation of `anaconda`. `tensorflow` is only available for 64 bit though, so in case that you have 64 bit windows (I suspect that it is the case), you should remove your installation of anaconda and reinstall using the 64 bit installer.